# How do I add back the default "Viewers of project" permission on a gcs bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I used this terraform resource to make a bucket public

```
resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_policy" "sdfsdf" {
  bucket = "sdfzdfsdf"
  policy_data = jsonencode({
    bindings = [
      {
        members = [
          "allUsers",
        ]
        role = "roles/storage.objectViewer"
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

Immediately after doing that I could no longer view the permissions of the bucket. I had to give my user Storage Admin.

I notice when I create a new bucket in the UI this permission is added:

```
`Viewers of project: my-project` 
Storage Legacy Bucket Reader
Storage Legacy Object Reader
```

My config removed that perm. How do I add it back? What is `Viewers of project: my-project`? What does this member binding look like in a policy json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be **very** careful with commands that overwrite|set resource policies.

[As you've discovered] these commands **replace** policies; they don't combine existing policies with what's provided.

It's almost always safer to use the equivalent of `add-iam-policy-binding`.

I assumed that buckets would not have a specific default policy (as I assumed they'd inherit from the project), but they (appear to) do (so):

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "projectEditor:[[PROJECT_ID]]",
        "projectOwner:[[PROJECT_ID]]"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "projectViewer:[[PROJECT_ID]]"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "projectEditor:[[PROJECT_ID]]",
        "projectOwner:[[PROJECT_ID]]"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyObjectOwner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "projectViewer:[[PROJECT_ID]]"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyObjectReader"
    }
  ],
]
```

What's also curious is that I've not encountered these `member` types before e.g. `projectEditor:[[PROJECT-ID]]`

What I would have thought should happen is that your user inherits from the project's policy.

What role does your identity have in the project that owns the bucket?

It's curious that you deleted your role binding from the bucket (with the above command) but that you were able to recover them; you must be inheriting sufficient permissions and so I'm surprised that you lost (inherited) permissions but were able to give them back to yourself.

It may be (but see above) that, if you're not already `Owner`, `Editor` (because these roles have intrinsic permissions on Cloud Storage), you could bind your identity to `roles/storage.admin` at the project level to give yourself an out in future but... again... how did you recover the role? Are you sure that you indeed lost it?

Comment: is `projectEditor:[[PROJECT-ID]]` the actual string? or is it `projectEditor:[[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]]` with the `[[]]`? Project Owner does not include `Storage Admin` by default. I also have IAM admin so I can grant myself any perms at the project level

Comment: No, replace `[[PROJECT-ID]]` with the value of the Project ID that owns the bucket